Getting flash of a white scaffold or a loading screen - flutter My Notes App
It seems like the issue you're encountering is that the theme is not applied immediately when the app starts, and there’s a delay before the correct theme is applied because you're waiting to load the theme preference from SharedPreferences. During this time, the app is rendering with the default Scaffold (which appears white) before it switches to the correct theme.
To fix this issue, we can optimize the theme loading by ensuring the correct theme is applied right from the start. You can do this by:
Setting the theme state as early as possible (before rendering the app’s main widget).
Using a splash screen or a loading screen while the theme preference is being loaded, so the UI doesn't flash white.
Solution
We'll modify the main() function to load the theme preference before the app starts rendering.
//main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'screens/home_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isDarkMode = true;
  bool _isLoading = true; // Indicates if the theme is still loading

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadThemePreference();
  }

  Future<void> _loadThemePreference() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _isDarkMode = prefs.getBool('isDarkMode') ?? false;
      _isLoading = false; // Loading is complete
    });
  }

  Future<void> _toggleTheme() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _isDarkMode = !_isDarkMode;
      prefs.setBool('isDarkMode', _isDarkMode);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_isLoading) {
      // Show a blank or splash screen while loading preferences
      return const MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ),
      );
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'My Notes App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      themeMode: _isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
      home: HomeScreen(
        toggleTheme: _toggleTheme,
        isDarkMode: _isDarkMode,
      ),
    );
  }
}


can you give updated code??
